# Setting Class-Level Variable to Use Between Event Handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a hard time understanding why the following code doesn't work. I'm sure it's something remedial that I'm missing or not understanding. I currently have a page that asks for user input. If, based on the input and logged in user, I find data from this page already in the database, I need to update the existing records rather than creating new ones, so I set a class-level bool to true. The problem is, when MyNextButton is clicked, PreviouslySubmitted is still false. So, I'm not sure how to make the value of this variable persist. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

```
public partial class MyForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private bool PreviouslySubmitted;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyButton.Click +=
            (o, i) =>
            {
                q = from a in db.TableA
                    where (a.SomeField == SomeValue)
                    select a;

                if(q.Any())
                {
                    PreviouslySubmitted = true;
                    //populate the form's fields with values from database for user to revise
                }
            }

        MyNextButton.Click +=
            (o, i) =>
            {
                //the value of PreviouslySubmitted is false at this point, 
                //even if I made sure it was set to true the previous postback

                if(PreviouslySubmitted)
                {
                    //update database
                }
                else
                {
                    //insert into database
            }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `PreviouslySubmitted` declared and/or set to `false`? I take it that `q.Any()` does return `true` and set the variable.

Comment: If the default value of PreviouslySubmitted is false, it could be that you are catching MyNextButton.click button event from a different instance of the class. See when your constructor is called.

Comment: @Chris - I added the class and bool declaration for clarity.

Comment: Are you sure that the `MyButton.Click` and `MyNextButton.Click` event handlers are firing in the order you expect them too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the previouslySubmitted variable as a static.

**Important update**
I'm sorry, I haven't check “based on the input and logged in user” part of the question.

Why it works is simple: there is no shared state between requests and postbacks of the page — it's a lack of HTTP protocol.

So, state of the page controls is being rebuilt on every request using the ViewState mechanism, but your own objects, fields and variables are not. Every page request (visitor) has it's own instance of MyForm class, but *static variables are common to all of them*. So, remove the static keyword and use ViewState/SessionState to store the value of PreviouslySubmitted variable per user.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating two event handlers.  Are you sure that they're called in the order that you expect?  If the second one was called first, you'd experience this problem.  You probably should combine the code for both event handlers into one.

Comment: Yeah, on the first page the user selects a value, submits. The event handler for that submit is the first one listed. After revising the form, the user clicks another submit button, which fires that second one. Although PreviouslySubmitted was set to true the previous event handler, the value wouldn't persist through to that second event handler. I declared it as static, as suggested by Artem, and that works, but I do not know why.